# Getting data from a website using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

I have a website http://www.rnbtop99.com/chart which I am trying to capture the list of songs, by artist and title.

I have the this simple PowerShell script as a start:

```
$site = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.rnbtop99.com/chart'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

However, I am confused of all the different Tag/Class/ID, how to match them up on the site to using PowerShell's functions and arrangements that I need to use as the various options to capture the data, e.g.

```
$site.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div')
$site.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('?')
```

Intellisense tells me I can use these options above, Tag/ClassName etc.

In Chrome using the inspect option it says for the artist - **class="artist-name ng-binding"**   however if I run `$site.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('artist-name ng-binding')` then it returns nothing.

Would be good to know also for future the best way for any site, where I can use either the Edge/Chrome the inspect option to get the correct element ID/Tag/ClassName then match up with the correct options to use in PowerShell to capture any data e.g. Document/ParsedHtml/All/Body/InnerHTML/InnerText etc etc.

Comment: Problem here is that all the elements you need are not part of the source, but dynamically loaded by inline javascript. `Invoke-WebRequest` fetches the source and parses it, but it doesn't actually render a full DOM and execute the javascript like your browser does.

Comment: How do you know it's Java Script?

Comment: I mean, what gives it away is Java Script, because i can use plan B, the Internet Explorer ComObject and RexEx to get the data, but i need to know how to look for Java Script so not to waste time next time using Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: If you look at the actual *source*, rather than in the Inspector in Chrome, you'll find that the markup only contains the "top part" of what is being rendered in your browser, and a script block that loads `/bundles/application.js` and sets up a bunch of listeners/callbacks. Internet Explorer ComObject works because Internet Explorer is an actual browser. I'm not familiar with plan B or RexEx, but if their web automation frameworks like Selenium, they probably also try to emulate browser behavior including script execution and full rendering

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$r=iwr  http://www.rnbtop99.com/api/chart/charts.json 
$j=$r.Content |convertfrom-json
$j.Previous.Tracks |%{"$($_.track.title) BY $($_.track.artist.name)"}
```

Comment: Got the latest version of PowerShell, the one on Windows 10. When I run this, it gives no errors, just this is the result:  **BY**      But if I run **$r.Content** after, it just lists a whole bunch of ransom numbers.

Comment: do ypu see the json file when accessing http://www.rnbtop99.com/api/chart/charts.json  with a browser ? this is working fine on my box (win7 and PSV4)

Comment: Using Chrome the link asks me to download a JSON file, using Edge it displays a massive long horizontal one single line. If I open the downloaed JSON file in Notepad++, it's also a massive big single horizontal line.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest seems to treat `application/json` as a byte stream. Try `$j=-join($r.Content-as[char[]]) |convertfrom-json` in the second line

Comment: Excellent, that works Mathias - thanks. But one more question for Kayasax, how did you get [http://www.rnbtop99.com/api/chart/charts.json](http://www.rnbtop99.com/api/chart/charts.json) from my original URL [http://www.rnbtop99.com/chart](http://www.rnbtop99.com/chart)?

Answer (score 0):

This is my final script pieced together with the help of all in this post. Just 4 lines, very nice. Small, but very effective.

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.rnbtop99.com/api/chart/charts.json"
#Invoke-WebRequest seems to treat application/json as a byte stream
$j=-join($r.Content-as[char[]]) |convertfrom-json
$j.Previous.Tracks |%{"$($_.track.artist.name) - $($_.track.title)"}
```